# Sidescrolling with touchpad?

Tags: 11.04, gnome, mouse, touchpad, settings

I just booted up my laptop and opened up my webbrowser. I went to OMG! Ubuntu!, and wanted to scroll as I always do, with the right side of my laptop's touchpad... It did not work...
I went to the Control Center to check if the option was still enabled... And after going through all of the options in the Control Center, I must come to a conclusion... **The option has been removed!**

Can anyone tell me why this usefull function has been removed and how to turn it back on again somehow? Preferably just having the option back and working in the correct dialog.
This one option made touchpad navigation 10 times easier in Ubuntu than it was in Windows... and now it appears they have removed it...

PLEASE!!! I BEG YOU!!!! *cough*

---

### 2 reboots fixed it for some strange reason...

Comment: These options will only show up if your mouse driver supports them, but if this worked previously for you, and you didn't do any major upgrades recently, I have no idea why this option would have disappeared.

Comment: They worked fine yesterday...

Comment: My touchpad doesn't have those options, but it never has.  To change overnight like yours did really smells like a bad update. If you have an 11.04 live CD handy, you may want to try testing with that.

Comment: @MichaelMS You've got to be kidding me... I just booted up the 11.10 alpha in VirtualBox and the option has magically disappeared there as well...

Comment: This tab is only shown when a touchpad is detected. I'd expect that it doesn't appear on VB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 reboots fixed it for some strange reason.

Answer (score 1):

It's still there on my computer, it's called Edge-Scrolling:

[image: se]

Comment: Not on my computer :s http://www.imgdumper.nl/uploads4/4e4403e4cbee4/4e4403e4c70c2-Schermafdruk-Muisvoorkeuren.png

Answer (score 1):

The simple resolution:

Open the terminal and execute:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse<br>
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

Done!! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Launch `gnome-mouse-properties` and see if it has a "Touchpad" tab where to enable sidescrolling.

Comment: The tab is missing: http://www.imgdumper.nl/uploads4/4e4403e4cbee4/4e4403e4c70c2-Schermafdruk-Muisvoorkeuren.png